# UIVisualEffectView and touches inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uivisualeffectview

I'm having an issue with using a UIVisualEffectView inside a custom UITableViewCell.

When the table cell is touched, the effect view seems to be switching Vibrancy on by itself which isn't the desired effect I'm after at all. Vibrancy also seems to keep itself switched on even after navigating to another view and back again.

Comment: Do you set UIVisualEffectView in code or in storyboard?

Comment: I set it in the Storyboard

Comment: Do you want to set it to single cell or whole table view?

Comment: Single cell. It works, however when you press on the cell it adds vibrancy for some reason :G

Comment: OK, Im going to check this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I think I found solution. The problem is with default selection of UITableViewCell. I think you code looks familiar to this:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        selectedBackgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: -1, y: -1, width: 1, height: 1))
        selectedBackgroundView?.backgroundColor = .clear
    }
}
```

and the effect is http://pl.tinypic.com/player.php?v=o00z1k&s=9#.WOpT5VLUTMU

but a small change a code:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        selectionStyle = .none
    }
}
```

and vibrancy effect will disappear.

Note, you can set it via storyboard

[image]